# xlsxwriter Spaces in sheet names, in formulas, having problems with quote marks

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm using xlsxwriter and I have a very specific problem that I cannot seem to find a solution to.

```
     formulaDB = '=IF(J{}<>"",COUNTIFS('DB Details'!A$1:A$9999,'App Details'!A{},'DB Details'!F$1:F$9999,"<>None"),"Not Selected")'.format(appRowCount, appRowCount)  
     worksheet3.write_formula('L'+str(appRowCount),formulaDB,rowColour)
```

My problem is all in the quotes.  For formulaDB I need to encapsulate the whole thing in single quotes.  Inside the actual formula, I need to use both single quotes and double quotes.  The single quotes inside the formula screw with the encapsulation.  The Sheet Name needs to use single quotes and the formula needs to use double quotes, while the whole variable needs to use single quotes...
I can re-name the sheet if need be, but that's a lot of work since it is referenced frequently throughout, and I am going for a very specific look in my output.
Did I miss something obvious?  I tried using various escape characters, but to no avail.

EDIT:  Yup, boneheaded problem on my part.  I did try escaping the single quotes earlier, but it had failed.  Seems I missed one, then missed it again when I reviewed my error.  Sorry folks, I should have been able to solve this one without asking for help.  Thank you, those of you who replied.

Comment: How about escaping those single and double quotes wherever needed or you can just surround the whole string with `" " "` such as `" " "STRING_PART" " "`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this was supposed to be a comment but I don't have enough reputation for it).

Maybe I'm missing something here, but why wouldn't escaping the single quotes work? I.e.

```
formulaDB = '=IF(J{}<>"",COUNTIFS(\'DB Details\'!A$1:A$9999,\'App Details\'!A{},\'DB Details\'!F$1:F$9999,"<>None"),"Not Selected")'.format(appRowCount, appRowCount)  
worksheet3.write_formula('L'+str(appRowCount),formulaDB,rowColour)
```

Of course without all the variable definitions I cannot check if this gives the output you want, but in a minimal example I replicated this seems to correctly write the formula in an excel cell, with the single quotes as expected (i.e. as Excel would expect to address different worksheet names).

Comment: Hm, I had escaped the single quotes before without success, but elected to try it again after your comment.  It worked.  I guess I missed one when I did it last, making this a bone-headed error on my part.  Sorry to eat up forum space.  Thanks for replying.